# How to integrate Ajax with Symfony2

Tags: ajax, symfony

I'm looking form simple tutorial/example about ajax in symfony2, for beginner?

I have these examples:

- city.php: http://pastebin.com/Qm8LS5kh
- ajax_req.js: http://pastebin.com/UqJMad24
- index.html: http://pastebin.com/H1err4Yh

How can these be put into a Symfony2 app?

Comment: Have you tried to create Entity/Form/Action/View with no ajax?

Comment: yes, i create  with no ajax

Comment: Show this code (with Symfony2) without ajax, please

Comment: Your question is horribly presented, but the answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 103, accepted):

It is easy. 
I will illustrate how to do an AJAX call in Symfony2 through 3 steps. For the following example, assume to use the jQuery library.

- Define the route for the action that has to handle your AJAX call. E.g.

  ```
  AcmeHomeBundle_ajax_update_mydata:
    pattern:  /update/data/from/ajax/call
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeHomeBundle:MyAjax:updateData }
  ```
- Define the action in the `MyAjax` controller from `Home` bundle. E.g.

  ```
  public function updateDataAction(){
    $request = $this->container->get('request');        
    $data1 = $request->query->get('data1');
    $data2 = $request->query->get('data2');
    ...
    //handle data
    ...
    //prepare the response, e.g.
    $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true);
    //you can return result as JSON
    return new Response(json_encode($response)); 
  }
  ```
- Prepare your `AJAX` call in your `Twig` template, e.g.:

  ```
  function aButtonPressed(){
      $.post('{{path('AcmeHomeBundle_ajax_update_mydata')}}',               
                  {data1: 'mydata1', data2:'mydata2'}, 
              function(response){
                      if(response.code == 100 && response.success){//dummy check
                        //do something
                      }

      }, "json");    
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {     
    $('button').on('click', function(){aButtonPressed();});
  });
  ```

  You can change the example by using other AJAX calls.

Comment: controller
http://pastebin.com/sPJkhpbY
routing
http://pastebin.com/mpb4X7CU
ajax.js
http://pastebin.com/tx70YNxz
view:
http://pastebin.com/9DvVPYMJ

when I open browser i only see:
{"code":100,"success":true}

I completely beginner

Comment: this means that we will have to write the js code in php ??

Comment: @wilsonrufus **NO!** JS is always executed on the client side, PHP at server side. Using ajax, you don't render the whole page at client side in one call. The client request for an URL. The server first returns the main PHP page with the JS code that I illustrated. Then, once the browser receive the response and load the main page (and finally document is ready), the JS code is executed. The JS code makes a call to a Symfony action (which is mapped by a unique URL) and waits for the result that is handled by JS.

Comment: Don't you need to test if request is xmlHttpRequest ??

Comment: Use new JsonResponse($data) instead of new Response(json_encode($data))

Comment: Thanks. It's working as expected & helps me a-lot to call ajax with symfony :)

Comment: For Symfony 2.2 and higher you can simply use `return new JsonResponse($response)` without encoding it.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32725054/5067173) Can anyone help me?

Comment: @zm455 read the PHP code first.