# Symfony JsonResponse return rendered template

Tags: symfony, templates, jsonresponse

After creating a new element using ajax, I get a JsonResponse from my conroller. Now I want to update the elements list. Therefor I want to have the new table as a variable in my JsonResponse.

How do I render a template in my Controller Action?

```
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity')->find($id);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        $template = $this->render('MyBundle:Entity:show.html.twig');
        return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'Success!'), 200);
```

When I add the "template"-line, i get an error on my jsonresponse. The entity is added to the database correctly.

My Template. show.html.twig

```
    <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Titel</th>
            <th>Link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ entity.titel }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.link }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My Call

```
$template = $this->render('MyBundle:Entity:show.html.twig', array('entities'=> $entities));
```

Comment: `$this->render(...` will work. What problems did you have with it?

Comment: I got a JsonResponse with error, after inserting this line. Is my routing correct? Bundlename:Entityname:Templatename? My template is placed in Resources/views/Entityname

Comment: Please post all relevant code/errors you have. Currently this is just guesswork. `$this->render` will give you a string (probably html), it all depends on how you further use this string.

Comment: I dont even use it. I just put it in a variable.

Comment: The error is still missing.

Comment: I've done this many times as well and never had any problems. I have a feeling, though, that you might have to pass the necessary variables to `MyBundle:ENtity:show.html.twig` when rendering. For example `$this->render('MyBundle:Entity:show.html.twig', array('entity' => $entity))`? Again, having an error and the relevant code would help, or we could keep guessing forever.

Comment: I dont get one. I debugged it with firebug and it holds on erroer function of my ajax call.

Comment: @LauraE. try opening the url you request through ajax directly in your browser.

Comment: this may be the problem. ill check it.

Comment: Could you pls give me a full example with: template, variables, aciion etc.?

Comment: What i want to do is: render 1 special table of my show.html.twig and send it via jsonresponse, to replace the old one

Comment: Seems like you absolutely don't know what you try to do, first you save just fetched entity, later you render template without any variables, and even you not pass the template to response...

Comment: y i donz pass it  yet, because i cant event get it.. this would be my next step.. im new to symfony and if this isnt the best way to get what i want, pls tell me a better one =)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for

Comment: Ok. I am adding a new element via ajax. Works perfect. Now I want to update the table, that shows all elements. I tried this with $('#id').load... but its very slow. That's why I want to send that table as part of my jsonresponse.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the json response, that's for sending data like arrays or objects to the view. you want to use `$this->render` and then as the ajax success function you can have something like this

```
function(msg){

    $e = $('your_element'); // this is where you want to display the received data
    $e.html(msg);
}
```

See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584591/how-to-integrate-ajax-with-symfony2) for more on ajax, Symfony2 and Json.

Comment: Can you please look at my edits above and try to figure out what I did wrong on calling the template?