# Symfony2 use with Ajax, to get the result of a query in doctrine

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

**UPDATE**

My function in repository of Ads

```
    public function findByExceptOwner($paramFetcher)
    {

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('ad');

        // parâmetros iniciais da query: status, departure de destination
        $query->select('ad');

        if(array_key_exists('type', $paramFetcher)){
            $query->from('DelivveWebBundle:' . $paramFetcher['type'], 'ad');
        }else{
            $query->from('DelivveWebBundle:Ad', 'ad');
        }

        $query
            ->where('ad.owner <> :ownerId')
            ->andWhere($query->expr()->eq('ad.status', ':status'))
            ->andWhere('ad.dateFinal <= :today')
            ->setParameter('ownerId', $paramFetcher['ownerId'])
            ->setParameter('status', 'new')
            ->setParameter('today', new \DateTime("now"));

        if (array_key_exists('departure',$paramFetcher)) {
            $departureArray = preg_split('/ - /', $paramFetcher['departure']);
            $departureCityArray = preg_split('/,/', $departureArray[count($departureArray) - 2]);
            $departureUFArray = preg_split('/,/', $departureArray[count($departureArray) - 1]);
            $departure = $departureCityArray[count($departureCityArray) - 1] . ' - ' . $departureUFArray[0];
            $query
                ->andWhere($query->expr()->like('ad.departure', ':departure'))
                ->setParameter('departure', "%{$departure}%");
        }

        if (array_key_exists('destination',$paramFetcher)) {
            $destinationArray = preg_split('/ - /', $paramFetcher['destination']);
            $destinationCityArray = preg_split('/,/', $destinationArray[count($destinationArray) - 2]);
            $destinationUFArray = preg_split('/,/', $destinationArray[count($destinationArray) - 1]);
            $destination = $destinationCityArray[count($destinationCityArray) - 1] . ' - ' . $destinationUFArray[0];
            $query
                ->andWhere($query->expr()->like('ad.destination', ':destination'))
                ->setParameter('destination', "%{$destination}%");
        }

        // raio de busca com centro nas coordenadas de departure
        if (array_key_exists('departure_latitude', $paramFetcher) && array_key_exists('departure_longitude', $paramFetcher) && array_key_exists('radius', $paramFetcher)) {
            $query
                ->andWhere('earth_distance_operator(earth_box(ll_to_earth(:departure_lat, :departure_lon), :radius), \'@>\', ll_to_earth(ad.departureLatitude, ad.departureLongitude)) = true')
                ->setParameter('departure_lat', floatval($paramFetcher['departure_latitude']), \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::FLOAT)
                ->setParameter('departure_lon', floatval($paramFetcher['departure_longitude']), \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::FLOAT)
                ->setParameter('radius', floatval($paramFetcher['radius']) / 1.609, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::FLOAT);
        }

        // raio de busca com centro nas coordenadas de destionation
        if (array_key_exists('destination_latitude', $paramFetcher) && array_key_exists('destination_longitude', $paramFetcher) && array_key_exists('radius', $paramFetcher)) {
            $query
                ->andWhere('earth_distance_operator(earth_box(ll_to_earth(:destination_lat, :destination_lon), :radius), \'@>\', ll_to_earth(ad.destinationLatitude, ad.destinationLongitude)) = true')
                ->setParameter('destination_lat', floatval($paramFetcher['destination_latitude']), \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::FLOAT)
                ->setParameter('destination_lon', floatval($paramFetcher['destination_longitude']), \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::FLOAT)
                ->setParameter('radius', floatval($paramFetcher['radius']) / 1.609, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::FLOAT);
        }

        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

I have the following method in the controller

```
public function searchAdsAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER', null, 'Unable to access this page!');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $owner = $this->getUser();

    $parameter = array();
    $parameter["departure_latitude"] = $request->request->get('departure_lat');
    $parameter["departure_longitude"] = $request->request->get('departure_long');
    $parameter["radius"] = Constant::RADIUS;
    $parameter["ownerId"] = $owner->getId();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('DelivveWebBundle:Ad')->findByExceptOwner($parameter);

    return new JsonResponse($entities);
}
```

my route this written as follows

```
search_ads:
pattern: /ad/search
defaults: { _controller: DelivveWebBundle:Ad:searchAds }
```

my function ajax

```
$(window).load(function() {
        var url = window.location.href;
        var urlArray = url.split("/");
        var path = urlArray[0]+"//"+urlArray[2];

        var departureLatitude = $("#bundle_ad_departureLatitude").val();
        var departureLongitude = $("#bundle_ad_departureLongitude").val();

        $.post(path+"{{ path('search_ads') }}",
            {departure_lat: departureLatitude, departure_long: departureLongitude},
            function (entities){
                alert("success ");
                console.log(entities);

                $(".panel-foot-information").remove();

                $div = "<div class='panel-foot-information row big-not-visible'>";

                 if (entities != null){
                 $div = $div + "<table id='ads'><thead><tr><th>Departure</th><th>Destination</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
                 $.each( entities, function( key, value ) {
                     $div = $div + "<tr class='ad-tr'>";
                     $div = $div + "<td class='hidden'><input type='hidden' id='idLat' value="+ value.departureLatitude +"/></td>";
                     $div = $div + "<td class='hidden'><input type='hidden' id='idLong' value="+ value.departureLongitude +"/></td>";
                     $div = $div + "<td>"+ value.owner.username +"</td>";
                     $div = $div + "<td>"+ value.departure +"</td>";
                     $div = $div + "<td>"+ value.destination +"</td>";
                     $div = $div + "<td class='packageType'>"+ value.packageType +"</td>";
                     $div = $div + "<td class='transportation'>"+ value.transportation +"</td>";
                     $div = $div + "<td class='price'>"+ value.price +"</td>";
                     $div = $div + "<td class='date'>"+ value.date + " - " + value.dateFinal +"</td>";
                     $div = $div + "</tr>";
                     alert($div)
                 });
                 $div = $div + "</tbody></table></div>";
                 }
                 $div = $div + "</div>";
                 $(".panel-middle").append($div);
            }, "json"
        );
    });
```

I tried another solution for those who saw my anterirormente question.

After much searching and doubt taken by several guys in stackoverflow could reach it, but when I go return on ajax he has a photo of the object type, this makes no sense.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Open the page directly in your browser and check the logs to see what triggered the 500 error. You can remove the AJAX code from your question since it seems unrelated to the 500 error.

Comment: Error 500 is reported by your server and presumably by your PHP code. Check that your controller works before using the output with AJAX.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your comments. If your AJAX doesn't work because you have an 500 error, fix it before going further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was in the JasonResponse could not serialize my class, then manipulated it to iterate power over the result in jQuery.

```
public function searchAdsAction(Request $request)
{
    ...
    $data = array();
    foreach($entities as $ad){
        $adArray = array();
        $adArray["departureLatitude"] = $ad->getDepartureLatitude();
        $adArray["departureLongitude"] = $ad->getDepartureLongitude();
        $adArray["owner_username"] = $ad->getOwner()->getUserName();
        $adArray["departure"] = $ad->getDeparture();
        $adArray["destination"] = $ad->getDestination();
        $adArray["packageType"] = $ad->getPackageType();
        $adArray["price"] = $ad->getPrice();
        $data[] = $adArray;
    }

    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your post helped me!