# Add data to tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, doctrine

this question is quite large, since what I would like to ask is how to add data to pd_procesos_acumulados.

[See Picture of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBzEa.png)

I'm actually working on Symfony and Workbench (In case it helps).
Basically, what I have is id_proceso (from pd_procesos_disciplinarios and will be saved to id_proceso_acumulado), and the user must input the id_acto (which will be saved into nro_interno_acum). An example of the URL where I get the id is this: "proceso/acumulacion/133"

Here is the Controller AcumulacionController:

```
/**
 * @param ProcesoDisciplinario $proceso
 *
 * @Route("/proceso/acumular/{id}", name="acumular_proceso")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @ParamConverter("proceso", class="ProcesoBundle:ProcesoDisciplinario")
 *
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function AcumularAction(int $acumula,ProcesoDisciplinario $proceso){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('ProcesoBundle:ProcesoDisciplinario');
    $procesado = $repository->findOneById($proceso); //el proceso al que se le atribuye
    $procesoAcumula = $acumula->get('procesoAcumuladoInput'); //el proceso a atribuir
    return array('procesados'=>$procesado, 'procesoAcumula'=>$procesoAcumula);
}
```

ProcesoDisciplinario $proceso is the id of the data I get from the website, and int $acumula is the id that the user must input.
Basically, i need the user to add as many id as it can, and all of them will have one same id_proceso_acumulado.

Here is the html:

```
 <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <form id="procesoAcumuladoForm">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Número de proceso" name="procesoAcumuladoInput" id="procesoAcumuladoInput">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-success" type="button" name="procesoAcumuladoGuardar" id="procesoAcumuladoGuardar" href="/proceso/acumulacion/{id}">Agregar Proceso</button>
                    </span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Preferably I would like that when the data is added to the table, the page wouldn't need to refresh to show changes.

The id of aa_actos_administrativos (named ActoAdministrativo):

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_acto", type="bigint", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

the id of pd_procesos_disciplinarios (named ProcesoDisciplinario)

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_proceso", type="bigint", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

In case i skipped something, please let me know. I know this is a big question, so please I beg your pardon in case it's too much. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question doesn't make clear what your actual problem is. From what I gathered, you have a data table display on a page, and a form that adds rows to that table. Am I correct in understanding that that part of your application is working, but you'd like to eliminate the need for a page refresh ever time a user adds data?

Comment: If I'm understanding the question properly, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584591/how-to-integrate-ajax-with-symfony2