# Symfony 2.5 - How to catch informations from a page to show it into an other page?

Tags: ajax, symfony, symfony-2.5

I'm really new in Symfony and AJAX and i hope you can explain me how should I do :

[image]
I have several elements in Page A, each of them corresponding to elements in several Pages B(1,2,3).

I want to catch elements from a specific Page like B2 and to show it in Page A with the matching element in Array AJAX.

A route already exists in Routing.yml for Folder Controller:

```
bundle_test:
resource: "@Bundle/Controller"
type: annotation
prefix: /
```

I have to create specifics routes ? How should i do ? Thx.

Comment: do you mean to carry variables from B2 to A?

Comment: Yes something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Page A, put this code

```
{% include 'twig from Pages B' with {'xxx': test, ...} %}
```

You can customize this code with yours. You can replace `test` with any variables from Page A. As for `xxx`, replace it with the variables from Pages B.

Comment: And what do you think about something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584591/how-to-integrate-ajax-with-symfony2 ?

Comment: this link is different with this question